# ffmpeg hangs while transcoding .dv to .mov

Tags: osx-lion, ffmpeg

I'm transcoding a bunch of files from .dv format to .mov

I already transcoded a bunch of them, but now ffmpeg keeps hanging. It transcodes in one case up to 2 min 06 sec (out of 2 min 44 sec) and stops. While transcoding, it uses both CPU cores (175%) but when it hangs it uses only one core (99%).

Here's the output of one run:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '/Volumes/Qmultimedia/iMovie Events.localized/Essen/clip-2006-02-11 20;43;56.dv' -vcodec libx264 -crf 21 -acodec aac -ac 2 -ab 192000 -strict experimental -vpre hq -vpre veryfast -refs 3 -deinterlace -threads 2 '/Users/mm/Desktop/videos/Essen/clip-2006-02-11 20;43;56.mov'
ffmpeg version 0.8.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 27 2011 14:25:30 with clang 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0
  libavformat  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[dv @ 0x7fbd41807c00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, dv, from '/Volumes/Qmultimedia/iMovie Events.localized/Essen/clip-2006-02-11 20;43;56.dv':
  Duration: 00:02:44.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28800 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: dvvideo, yuv420p, 720x576, 28800 kb/s, PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0.2: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1024 kb/s
File '/Users/mm/Desktop/videos/Essen/clip-2006-02-11 20;43;56.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 0x7fbd41402e40] w:720 h:576 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:16/15 sws_param:
[libx264 @ 0x7fbd4181c600] using SAR=16/15
[libx264 @ 0x7fbd4181c600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fbd4181c600] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fbd4181c600] 264 - core 116 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=21.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 pb_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to '/Users/mm/Desktop/videos/Essen/clip-2006-02-11 20;43;56.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.4.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=10-51, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libfaac, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 192 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=7080 bitrate=2397.9kbits/s    
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
    Last message repeated 1 times
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=71
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=69
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=65
    Last message repeated 1 times
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=66
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=65
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=66
[dvvideo @ 0x7fbd41819c00] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
frame= 3175 fps= 54 q=24.0 size=   28308kB time=00:02:06.56 bitrate=1832.3kbits/s
```

Comment: FFmpeg 0.9 is out, maybe try with this? Have you also posted to the FFmpeg user's mailing list? There are some developers involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. FFmpeg 0.9 is working for me. Missed to update my brew formula before installing ffmpeg :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you always update to the latest FFmpeg version, in your case 0.9.

If you've installed FFmpeg using a package manager like Homebrew, don't forget to update the packages themselves:

```
brew update
brew upgrade ffmpeg
```

Comment: On OSX 10.7 I needed to use the `--use-clang` switch: `brew upgrade --use-clang ffmpeg` (see: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8815 )

Answer (score 0):

you can clone it from main here: git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git There have been a few improvements which might improve your transcoding workload. The changelog can be viewed here: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=log